# Как отцентрировать содержимое хедера при резиновой вёрстке?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Сделал сайт резиновым по горизонтали, но столкнулся со следующим:
Содержимое хедера, при уменьшении ширины страницы, на ширине примерно 920px вылазит за левую границу.
Также, содержимое хедера не центрируется при сужении ширины страницы.
Спасибо!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
/*This is CSS RESET*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/

body, html {
 background-color: #B63D32;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page-wrapper {
 font: 100%/1.4em,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
header{
 width: 90%;
 height: 202px;
 /*border*/
 border-top: 22px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*border ends*/
}
.container {
 width: 898px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
 width: 59px;
 height: 86px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.title__first {
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
 text-align: center;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px; 
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-left: -3.5px;
}
.title__second {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
 letter-spacing: -0.55px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 3px;
}
.main__menu {
 width: 630px;
 height: 15px;
 float: none;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-top: 13px;
}
.menu {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
}
ul {
 padding-top: 11px;
}
.menu li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 19px;
 font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bolder;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
#izdeliya {
 padding-left: 20px
}
#O__nas {
 padding-left: 192px;

}
#Kontakty {
 padding-left: 182px;
}
section {
 width: 90%;
 height: 640px;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -16px;

 /*border ends*/ 
}
.container1 {
 height: 640px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 background-color: #BFBFBF;
}
.spisok {
 height: 640px; 
 width: 230px;
 background-color: #7B2019;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
 border-left: 0px solid #000;
 border-right: 18px solid #000;
 /*border ends*/ 
} 
.spisok li {
 width: 180px;
 height: 45px;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 3px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 16px;
 background-color: #B63D32;
 border-radius: 2px;
 /*This is START of button shadow*/
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0.1px black;
 border-top: 1.4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
 border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
 border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
 }

.text-div {
 width: 158px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -9px;

}
.spisok li a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding-top: 17px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 position: relative;
 display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    text-align: center;
}






footer {
 width: 90%;
 height: 115px;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*border ends*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>ШвейПокров</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
     <img src="img/Krest_logo.jpeg" alt="ШвейПокров" class="logo"> 
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
     <div class="title__first">
      "ШвейПокров"
     </div>
     <h1>Православная швейная мастерская</h1>
     <div class="title__second">
      доставка по всей России
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__menu">
     <ul class="menu">
      <li>
       <a href="#" id="izdeliya">Изделия</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#" id="Kontakty">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#" id="O__nas">О нас</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>

  <section>
   <div class="container1">
    <div class="spisok">
     <ul>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Облачения</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Подризники</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Стихари</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Рясы</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Подрясники</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Головные уборы</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Для монахов</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Крещальные наборы</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Венчальные наборы</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Облачения для храма</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Вышитые кресты</a></li>
      <li><a class="text-div" href="#">Кадильный уголь</a></li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 
  <footer>
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
  </footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно использовать `flexbox`, довольно удобный инструмент с достаточной поддержкой браузерами на сегодня. Так же можно отцентровать блок, задав ему ширину по контенту (`.titles`) и прописав `margin: 0 auto;`. Данное свойство в таком виде автоматически рассчитывает одинаковые внешние отступы справа/слева при прописанной ширине блока. Для меню же поможет только ширина в процентах (или, разумеется, `flexbox`)

Answer (score 0):

При разработке адаптивной версии переводите ширину на проценты и будет Вам счастье.

P.S. *Православная швейная мастерская* убило...

Comment: А что здесь такого?)

Comment: Ширину абсолютно всех элементов?

Comment: Большинства, особенно всяких враперов, которые имеют фиксированную ширину и удерживают контент посередине страницы, например: `width: 90%; margin: 0 auto` остальные блоки внутри могут занимать хоть по 100% при маленьких размерах экрана

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы :)
DeamonHK, подскажите, пожалуйста, а почему элементы, включенные в хедер, выходят за рамку? Вот сам сайт: shveypokrov.ru

Comment: У Вас меню и шапка как были в пикселях, так и остались в адаптиве, делайте на процентах

Comment: А margin и padding тоже в процентах?

Comment: @DaMarkuzz только справа и слева, если нужны, сверху и снизу можно фиксированные ставить